# Página Imprimir não centralizada

Tags: html, css

Estou enfrentando um pequeno problema, ao clicar no botão "submit" para imprimir uma determinada página, mas ela não fica centralizada no navegador do sistema operacional windows.

Segue o printscreen do errado e a errada(a segunda imagem):

[image: Página errada]

[image: Página que seria correta]

Segue o código css:

```
    html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ati-guia-form {
  font-size: 12px !important;
  color: #ddd;
}
.ati-guia-form .ati-form-head {
  /*padding: 10px 0 10px !important;*/
  border-bottom: 4px solid #045745 !important;
  /*margin-bottom: 9px !important;*/
  margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.ati-guia-form .ati-form-head img {
  width: 190px !important;
}
.ati-guia-form .ati-form-head ul > li {
  text-indent: -4em !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
}
.ati-guia-form .ati-form-head h1 {
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-size: 11px !important;
  color: #045745 !important;
}
.ati-guia-form .ati-form-body {
  -moz-placeholder-color: transparent !important;
  -ms-input-placeholder-color: transparent !important;
}
.ati-guia-form .ati-form-body label {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.ati-guia-form .ati-form-body h2 {
  font-size: 14px !important;
}
.ati-guia-form .ati-form-body label[class^='checkbox-inline'] {
  /*padding: 5px 1px 0 !important;*/
}
.ati-guia-form .ati-form-body h3 {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  margin: 140px 0 16px 0 !important;
  padding-top: 3px !important;
}
input[class^='ati-btn-'] {
  display: none !important;
}
.ati-guia-form .ati-form-body .form-control {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.ati-guia-form .ati-form-body .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 8px !important;
}
.ati-guia-form .ati-form-body ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent !important;
}
.ati-guia-form .ati-form-body ::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent !important;
}
div#popmake-97{
  background-color: black !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
#page{
  display: none !important;
}

label.checkbox-inline {
    height: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
}
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    float: left;
}
label.checkbox-inline {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
}

label.checkbox-inline input {
    /*float: left;*/
    /*margin: 3px;
    margin-left: 10px;*/
    margin-top: -15px;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}







  * {
    /*height: 10px !important;*/
    color: #000000 !important;
    background: #000000 !important;
    border-color: #000000 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    /*font-size: 20px !important;*/
    margin-bottom: 3px !important;
  }
  .pum-theme-487 .pum-title{
    display: none !important;
  }
  .ati-guia-form .ati-form-head div.col-xs-4 > h1{
    font-size: 16px !important;
  }
  .ati-guia-form .ati-form-head{
    padding-bottom: 50px !important;
  }
  .form-group input {
      margin-top: 10px !important;
  }
  .ati-form-body {
    /*margin-top: 50px!important;*/
  }

  .container-fluid.rodape1{
    display:none !important;
  }
  .container-fluid.rodape2{
    display:none !important;
  }
  .container-fluid.copy{
    display:none !important;
  }
  input{
    height: 24px !important;
  }
  .ati-guia-form .ati-form-head h1 {
      font-size: 12px;
  }

  .ati-guia-form .ati-form-head img {
      width: 250px;
  }

  .ati-guia-form .ati-form-head {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
  }

  label {
      font-size: 11px !important;
  }

  .ati-guia-form .ati-form-head {
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
  }

  body .ati-guia-form .ati-form-head h1 {
      margin: 0 !important;
      font-size: 11px !important;
  }

.ati-form-body p {
    display: none;
}
.ati-form-body p {
    display: none;
}
button.pum-close.popmake-close {
    display: none;
}
```

*Obs.: A segunda imagem é no Mac OS X*

Comment: Testou só no Safari ou em outros browsers tb? Essa janela é controlada pelo user-agent do browser e tem comportamento padrão... a não ser que vc esteja chamando essa window.print com JS... Ai pode ser que esteja buggando alguma coisa

Comment: Já fiz o teste, no mac ele funciona normalmente, já no windows fica cortado como se tivesse um padding mas não tem.

Comment: No CSS coloca `@page { margin:0mm;}` e olha se melhora alguma coisa... é só um teste, não sei se vai dar certo ai

Comment: Fiz o teste ainda nada, é muito estranho....

Comment: Já fiz o teste, o problema é que parece que no windows não está ledo o @page print

Comment: É pq no CSS tem que ficar assim `@media print { @page {margin: 0mm;} }`